# Database design/storing formulas in the database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm making an app that has to do a lot of different calculations based on user answers(mostly YES/NO and some numbers) and every different combination has a different message/text to be displayed. So I thought I'll just store all the different combinations (less then a 500 total) in MySQL and fetch the message I need. But what do I do with the formulas ? Most combinations have different formula that depends on the user input. I thought of storing them as string and writing a parser, but it doesn't seem right.

Here's an example:

```
> Graduated with above 3.5 GPA: 0(YES), 1(NO)
> 
> Attends College: 0(YES), 1(NO)
> 
> Makes less then 20,000 yearly: 0(YES) 1(NO)
> 
> Age: Number
> 
> Working Experience: Number
```

So the forumula will be something like `(60+(10*X)+(15 *Y))` but slightly different for every combination. So I put all the 8 possible combinations in the DB with the according formula and message.

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: I worked with a developer who went down the road of trying to store formulas in the database that were later used for calculations. It was a survey app. It turned out to be incredibly slow and difficult to maintain the formulas (code in database is nearly impossible to read).  I suggest that you follow an object-oriented paradigm and use a factory to look up and invoke the correct formula, written as the implementation of a well-known interface.

Comment: Smells like a dup...  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=storing+formulas+in+the+database